# Instructed or something like

Tags: sentence-usage

Suppose I posted something on social media and i don't want ladies to watch them then can I say like that.

Ladies are instructed to not watch those pics, you may find visual violence or something. Please tell me how to say it grammatically correct it's a kind of warning.

Answer (score 1):

The closest natural phrasing to what you have written is

> Ladies are advised not to view these pictures as they may depict violence.

This sounds very sexist, though, and I'm not very sensitive to sexism. I have used the word "advise" because "instruct" implies that you are in a position to order someone not to view something, which seems very unlikely to me.

There are a few standard ways of saying something like this, which you see all over:

> These images may depict graphic violence.  Viewer discretion is advised.

or

> Warning: These images may depict graphic violence, which some viewers may find disturbing.

Comment: What if I want to say, this picture contains obscene matters that you may find disturbing

Comment: "Obscene" usually refers to something sexually repugnant, not violent.  What you say depends on the content of your picture.  If it's of a sexual nature you could say "This picture contains sexual material that some may find offensive." or replace "sexual" with "pornographic" if appropriate. Normally sexual stuff is called "offensive," violent stuff is called "disturbing."